# Moser invariant curves in discrete dynamical systems and how they give stability

Tags: discrete-mathematics, dynamical-systems, chaos-theory, discrete-calculus, diffeomorphism

I have seen a theorem which says that under certain hypothesis, given an elliptic fixed point $P$ for particular discrete dynamical systems ($X_{k+1}=S(X_k)$ with $S$ a conservative diffeomorphism not depending on time), there are invariant curves for every neighborhood of $P$ called Moser curves. Then it is concluded that if I have these curves, then the point is stable. I don't understand something though.

If I consider the region between two such invariant curves, why should the internal points into internal points of the image? I mean, the boundary given by these curves stays the same because of invariance, but why does the interior points get mapped to interior points?
If I had a continous dynamical system I could say that every solution would be bound to stay in that set because otherwise it should pass through a Moser curve, violating the uniqueness of solution. But for discrete systems, why does this happen?

Is it true that a diffeomorhphism sends interior points to interior points? Or is it because there is also the hypothesis of the diffeomorphism being conservative?

Comment: You said it all: the map is a diffeomorhism, so continuous.

Comment: yeah, ok, but take for example $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$ and the map that sends $x$ to $\frac{x}{|x|^2}$. It is continuous, but the inside of the ball of unitary radius is sent outside, and viceversa

Comment: It is a fixed point...

Comment: Who? $P$? So what? I'm sorry I can't see your point. The problem is not about $P$, it's about the points in the neighborhood. I can't see why the fact that $P$ is a fixed point and the map a diffeomorphism should solve the problem. At least not in this discrete case